# I would like to know of a site that would be useless if JavaScript was disabled

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a site that if I disabled JavaScript the site would be useless, and what other functions would I not be able to use. Does anyone have a name of a site that I can look at? I want to know what no longer works.

Comment: `javascript:(function()%7B%20window.open('http://stackoverflow.com/');%20%7D)();`

Comment: Thank you to the people that answered my question without the smartass answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the popularity of the question, this one doesn't even load w/o JS.

http://www.graphikdesign.it/

Answer (score 3):

You're looking at one right now.

Comment: @randywhite30: Have you tried, you know... disabling JavaScript in your browser and checking?  It's kind of pointless to ask questions you are fully capable of answering yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Not quite sure if this is really programming related... but YouTube and Google Docs for instance.

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net

Most sites that use javascript heavily become *less* useful rather than *useless*.  In order to do that, many of them will implement the important parts twice - once with javascript, and a less sophisticated version without.

Answer (score 0):

Google.com looses it's Instant search capability with Javascript off.